# Can squid be used in reverse or any other package be used in reverse

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, minecraft

I'm attempting to host a minecraft game server. The primary obstacle is that the network I'm using only has 1 mbps upload. I have a vps available that has 1Gbps both ways. I would like to have the users able to sign in and have their worlds cached on the VPS. I have a massive amount of ram on my home server. With that said. The VPS I am using as well as I would REALLY prefer to use has a cap on 4 Gigs of ram. Suggestions are respected, however I would be happier with solutions.

Home server has ubuntu 14.04 as well as the VPS. If you're willing to give a step by step, that would be enjoyed. I'm just as comfortable with package names and an over view of the concepts included. Any help would be appreciated. The only reason I'm asking this here, is that everything I find using the keywords I understand would fit the situation come up with results pertain to DNS.

Comment: Squid caches/proxies HTTP/HTTPS traffic.  I am not sure of the protocol Minecraft uses for multiplayer, and even if it is HTTP/HTTPS not everything HTTP/HTTPS is cacheable.  You would probably have to have some type of caching server that's built/developed to work with Minecraft specifically.  I have not heard of one and don't think one exists.

Comment: It was worth a shot. Thank you for your time ^^